# Dictionary: Open Source Project

Tags: open-source, dictionary

I'm looking for a open source project for dictionary for a language (probably you never heard of it) which has not been "digitized". The dictionary will be from one language to several others, and several others to THE language. Since the language has not been "digitized", I need following features along with searching a word:

1 - Add your own translation to existing words/phrases

2 - Add a new word/phrase and add translation

3 - Request a word/phrase to be translated

4 - Rate (like/dislike or rate within the range) the translation (depending on the rating "correctness" get points")

5 - Possibly relate words (especially nouns) with pictures

6 - Easier to implement mobile version of it

I guess it's more "collaboration site", than dictionary. So the project I'm looking for may not be called as "Dictionary".

I know it's possible to design and write from the scratch, but would be good to begin with something in hand, especially if you are just spending your time/effort for non-profit stuff.

I'm looking around for the project, but didn't find something useful. At the same time designing the architecture in my mind.

If you could share some open source projects, it would be really great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure what *exactly* you need, but would [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Main_page) be of any help? There are *a lot* of localized variations to support different languages and there will probably be a way to ask them to support your language of interest, if it is not already there.

Comment: Actually what I want to implement is same as this one (in terms of functionality). But this wiki does not meat my ALL requirements, since I do have other parts of the project also such as knowledge test, tutorial, lecture, history etc. What I mean is - I can't  develop other parts of the project in wiki. Same thing in a form of project (C#, Java or other lang.) would meet my need. Thanks for pointing it out.